# Open local browser with c# aplication running in local docker container

Tags: c#, docker, browser, process, containers

I have an application running net core 6 with c#, it is opening the local browser from time to time, but I want to put the application in the docker container, and there, when the application runs, the browser does not open from my machine. here is my code

```
var url = "url to open";
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = uri;
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: A container is 'headless' and doesn't have a desktop available where it can open desktop apps. If your program needs to be able to open a browser, then it's not a good candidate for containerization.

Comment: right that's what I imagined, so I'll have to run the program outside the container. thanks.